# trying to remove rows with some conditions with drop function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove rows with certain values, I used drop function and also kept inplace parameter as True but when I am writing the dataframe to new file it is not removed.

here is my code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

assessment = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset new/students_Vle3_registration_info.csv')
assessment = assessment.values
i=0
n=[]
for assm in assessment[:,13:14]:
    if(assm=='Withdrawn'):
        n.append(i)
    i=i+1

assessment = pd.DataFrame(assessment)
assessment.drop(n,inplace=True )
assessment.to_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset new/students_Vle3_registration_info_withdraw_removed.csv')
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: We need to know how your dataframe and how the array looks like you are generating in the loop. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Are you sure that your for loop condition actually catches anything? Try adding a print statement to the conditional in the for loop to see which lines it captures.

Comment: yes it does for loops is working fine I have checked, I think the problem is after the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having much information I would rather use a vectorized approach:

```
import pandas as pd

assessment = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset new/students_Vle3_registration_info.csv')

condition = (assessment[col13].str.contains('Withdrawn')) | (assessment[col14].str.contains('Withdrawn'))

#col13 and col14 are the columns in your dataframe you are selecting by

assessment = assessment.drop(assessment[condition].index)
```